# Drawing a rounded rectangle on an html canvas doesn't seem to work when called inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Drawing a rounded rectangle on an html canvas doesn't seem to work when called inside of a loop
I'm trying to make a simple html canvas game where I render a grid of rounded rectangles. The problem is while rendering a default rectangle works, rendering a rounded rectangle appears to not render at all and the canvas changes to blank, it renders perfectly when called onces outside of the render loop.
Here is what I tried so far

```
const c = document.createElement('canvas');
c.width = innerHeight / 2; c.height = innerHeight / 2;
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(c);
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');

class Letter {
    i; x; y; w; h; r; t;
    constructor(i, x, y, w, h, r, t) {
        this.i = i; this.x = x;
        this.y = y; this.w = w;
        this.h = h; this.r = r;
        this.t = t;
    }

    render() {
        for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                this.r = { tl: this.r, tr: this.r, br: this.r, bl: this.r };
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r.tl, this.y);
                ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.w - this.r.tr, this.y);
                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x + this.w, this.y, this.x + this.w, this.y + this.r.tr);
                ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.w, this.y + this.h - this.r.br);
                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x + this.w, this.y + this.h, this.x + this.w - this.t.br, this.y + this.h);
                ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.r.bl, this.y + this.h);
                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x, this.y + this.h, this.x, this.y + this.h - this.r.bl);
                ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y + this.r.tl);
                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x, this.y, this.x + this.r.tl, this.y);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                ctx.fill();
                // ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
            }
        }
    }
}

const rows = 5, cols = 5;
var radius = 16;
var grid = [];
var counter = 0;
for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    grid[row] = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        grid[row][col] = new Letter(
            counter++, //id
            ((c.width / rows) * col), //x coordinate
            ((c.height / cols) * row), //y coordinate
            Math.round((c.width / rows) - 8),// width 8
            Math.round((c.height / cols) - 8),// height 8
            16,// radius            
            'B',// letter

        );
    }
}

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            const l = grid[row][col];
            l.render();
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Comment: What is the line `this.r = { tl: this.r, tr: this.r, br: this.r, bl: this.r };` supposed to do? Also, do you know there is now a [`roundRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/roundRect) method (with [a polyfill](https://github.com/Kaiido/roundRect/) I made).

Comment: that adds a radius topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight for the rounded rectangle, and thanks for the polyfill I'll check it!

Comment: But this breaks your code. At the next call, you'll do `this.r = { tl: { tl: 23, ...`, at the call after that, that would be `this.r = { tl: { tl: { tl: 23` Maybe you wanted this to be in the constructor only?

Comment: thanks that fixed it, I just don't know how it worked for a single call to the function and not inside a loop, again thanks for pointing out